# nicescroll, need to resize automatically when div changes it size

Tags: jquery, nicescroll

I have `<article>` tag, which contains lot of text and it's usually showed with a jquery nicescroll beside, but if it contains an element which can change height 'some collapsable element) of the  `<article>` tag and nicescroll doesn't want to reload.

my code:

```
<article class="item">
  <div class="reference">some text</div>
  <a href="#long-2" data-toggle="collapse" class="reference-long arr_down"></a>
  <div id="long-2" class="collapse">some text</div>
</div>
```

if I click on `a`, the `article` becomes bigger but I need to reload the nice scroll, when the collapsed item is clossed again, I need do the same.

jquery, which works just sometimes and doesn't work in the Safari browser:

```
$(document).ready(
function() {
$("article").niceScroll({cursorcolor:"#fff",autohidemode:false, zindex: 999});
}
);
$(function() {  
$('.reference-long').click(function(){
    $("article").getNiceScroll().remove();
    $("article").niceScroll({cursorcolor:"#fff",autohidemode:false, zindex: 999});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `resize()` function instead of `remove()`

```
$("article").getNiceScroll().resize();
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the solution

```
$("article").getNiceScroll().resize();
```

but note that if you are using any animation, you must allow the animation to be completed before calling the `.resize()` function.

Example:

```
$('.reference-long').click(function(){
    $("#long-2").slideToggle(function(){
        $("article").getNiceScroll().resize();
    });
});
```